# Unexpected rendering (css transform) on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser, transform

Please take a look at this pen...
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjeYNM

```
`<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="card-preview-cont">
    <div class="envelope">
      <div class="env-section env-front"></div>
      <div class="env-section env-back">
        <div class="section-content">
          <div class="env-front--flap">
            <div class="svg-responsive-cont">
              <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 536 184.1" enable-background="new 0 0 536 184.1" xml:space="preserve">
                <path fill="black" d="M535.9,0L0,0l254.3,178.3c0,0,6.4,5.6,13.5,5.8l0,0c7.8,0,16.1-5.2,16.1-5.2L535.9,0z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-wrap">
            <div class="card-section card-cover">card outer</div>
            <div class="card-section card-cover--inner">card inner</div>
            <div class="card-section card-base">card base</div>
          </div>
          <div class="env-front-cover-wrap">
            <div class="env-front-cover"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

When clicking on the envelope it flips and the card goes out..
Clicking on the card should open it.
on chrome it works perfect, even on IE it mostly works fine (besides the card flickering). BUT on Firefox i cant get the card to open the right way (:X)

can some one figure out what is the problem on Firefox?
and if you can also find a way to fix the IE flickering when the card slides up, it will be awesome!

thanks in advance.